# How to print variables during Forward_gpu in caffe

Tags: c++, machine-learning, deep-learning, caffe

I tried to print bottom shape and bottom data during Forward_gpu function. But it will cause segment fault. Could someone please tell me the right way to do this and the reason why I got segment fault?

I did:

```
void Forward_gpu(const vector<Blob<Dtype> *> &bottom, const vector<Blob<Dtype> *> &top)
{
  ...
  puts("bottom shape: ");
  std::cout << bottom[2*i]->gpu_shape()[0] << std::endl;
  ...
}
```

What I got:

```
bottom shape:
*** Aborted at 1500362213 (unix time) try "date -d @1500362213" if you are using GNU date ***
PC: @     0x7fe4be27cbfd caffe::DeformableConvolutionLayer<>::Forward_gpu()
*** SIGSEGV (@0x1020d602c00) received by PID 17153 (TID 0x7fe4bea969c0) from PID 224406528; stack trace: ***
    @     0x7fe4bc615cb0 (unknown)
    @     0x7fe4be27cbfd caffe::DeformableConvolutionLayer<>::Forward_gpu()
    @     0x7fe4be204471 caffe::Net<>::ForwardFromTo()
    @     0x7fe4be2047e7 caffe::Net<>::ForwardPrefilled()
    @     0x7fe4be224455 caffe::Solver<>::Step()
    @     0x7fe4be224d59 caffe::Solver<>::Solve()
    @           0x4084be train()
    @           0x405cac main
    @     0x7fe4bc600f45 (unknown)
    @           0x40647d (unknown)
    @                0x0 (unknown)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to access them like this

```
bottom[2*i]->shape(0)
```

and make sure that 2*i is in the range of available bottoms,first try with

```
bottom[0]->shape(0)
```

to make sure at least you can get it to print

Comment: Well...sorry to bother again. Could you please tell me how to print bottom data? I tried bottom[2 * i]->gpu_data_at(1, 1, 0, 0) and I got an address,
 however I cannot convert it to a value... like (int*) and (double*) and (Dtype*). They all didn't work.

Comment: I tried \*((float*)bottom[2 * i]->cpu_data_at(0, 0, k, j)). It worked fine. Thanks.

Comment: @baNv,glad it worked...but i always thought bottom[2*i]->cpu_data() will do,or bottom[2*i]->mutable_gpu_data() in case of gpu to get access to the blob contents but not sure...